# Example of two differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with special conditions

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a domain.
I tried to construct a triangle $\Delta\subset D$ and two continuously differentiable functions $u(x,y),v(x,y)\in C^1(\Delta)$ with the following conditions:

1. $u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)\neq0\,$ for $(x,y)\in\Delta$.
2. $\iint_{\Delta} u(x, y) dx dy = 0$
3. $\iint_{\Delta} v(x, y) dx dy = 0$

My attempt is $u(x,y)=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}y\right)$ and $\,v(x,y)=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi x}y\right)$ and triangle $\Delta$ with vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)$.

But the functions above are not continuous at $(0,0)$. Maybe someone can see how to construct such an example?

For some rectangle $[0,2\pi]\times[0,b]$ it is easy to take $\sin(x),\,\cos(x)$ (extended to the rectangle), but for a triangle this is not obvious.